# Make in-line space between words in HTML in an easy way

Tags: html

I know this is a beginner's question, but I don't know how to phrase it in Google.

Essentially, I have an ordered list that is printed as follows:

1. Carrots
2. Potatoes
3. Onions

And I want to change the HTML code to print something like this:

1. Carrots (several spaces here, to create a void) "some other stuff"
2. Potatoes (several spaces here, to create a void) "some other stuff"
3. Onions (several spaces here, to create a void) "some other stuff"

What I mean by (several spaces here, to create a void) is essentially about 5 ' ' (5 spaces) that will separate the text visually.

Is there a way to represent the spaces in a **HTML** element, just like Tab does in an IDE(where it puts some space from the beginning of the line to indent the code)?

Comment: I think you want an `hr` tag ( Horizontal Rule ) which you can style with CSS to make it of particular length, colour and style

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius — Really not. That is used to put a hard divide between content. The goal here is to *connect* content not divide it.

Comment: There are some excellent solutions in the linked question that was asked a decade ago. OnionStand's answer is a good use of modern browser features.

Comment: @Quentin - the aim of the OP is becoming clearer as time progresses but was not immediately obvious just from the above question

Comment: I would guess they are great solutions, however I don't know CSS and I don't have the time at the moment to fly blind and try to run stuff I don't know 100% what is does.

Comment: @KostasM — CSS is the layout language of the WWW, if you want to know layout and don't know CSS: learn.

Comment: I am aware of that, it's just not my top priority at the moment. I will learn CSS when the time is proper, as I'm trying to learn HTML and PHP right now

Comment: If you're not going to learn the layout language, don't concern yourself with layout.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible yet. The only way that I know is that you can apply `margin` to your tag, like this.

```css
p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.first {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.first, .second {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello</span>
<span>World</span>
<p>You'll see now that it has space because of the margin I applied on CSS.</p>
<span class="first">Hello</span>
<span class="second">World</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

As per the comment above I think you want to use an `HR` tag which you can easily style with CSS.

```css
li{
  margin:1rem auto;
}
hr{
  width:200px;
  margin:1rem;
  border:none;
  border-top:1px dotted grey;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1<hr>Some text 1</li>
  <li>Item 2<hr>Some text 2</li>
  <li>Item 3<hr>Some text 3</li>
  <li>Item 4<hr>Some text 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Although I can somehow see this working, it isn't 100% what I'm looking for because I want an easy way to write it like this: `Item 1                       Some text 1`, meaning I want to have 1 line of text for both of these. I get that what I wrote can be misread and answered by your reply(I will take note of the `<hr>` tag, it's quite useful), but are you aware of any ways to do what I wrote in this comment?

Comment: Perhaps if you were to add your actual code and not simply describe something to which we should guess?

Comment: I edited by comment above to better describe my predicament, does it clear things up?

Comment: Do you want to put dashes or space?

Comment: Spaces, but I wrote it as dashes in the question because multiple spaces would only be registered as 1 space.

Comment: If the aim is to add blank space there is no handy shortcut such as `tab` - a single space is represented by `&nbsp;` and these can be repeated to form a large, blank space. HTML ignores multiple spaces written in the code and will display as a single space.  You could perhaps accomplish your goal with a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Comment: Don't use multiple non-breaking spaces as a hack to simulate a margin. We have CSS for that.

Comment: My answer doesn't answer your needs?